# react-router-dom <Link/> is clearing the {history,match,location} props when clicked in ssr application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server-side, react-router-dom

I could not implement the Link component in server-side rendering.

```
<Link to={`/edit/${id}`}>
  <h3>{description}</h3>
</Link>
```

In `/edit` page, I have this line of code to test the props that passed:

```
<h1>{props.match.params.id}</h1>
```

this throws an error because **match** prop is not passed.

If I used `<a></a>` instead of `<Link/>` wrapped `/edit` page with **withRouter** I get those props however this time I am disconnected from the store.

Since `<Link/>` navigates inside react-router looks like props that passed to components are cleared up when I click on `<Link/>`. I could not figure out how to solve the issue.

I added `historyApiFallback:true` to webpack.config devServer object but it did not solve the issue.

[here is the repo](https://github.com/yilmazbingo/Universal-Budget-App/blob/form/src/components/ExpenseListItem.js)

Answer (score 4):

Your exact mistake is using `href` prop for the react-router `Link` component. you should use `to`, like below:

```
<Link to={`/edit/${id}`}>
  <h3>{description}</h3>
</Link>
```

After fixing this issue, directly you will fall into another issue. you will get it inside `EditExpensePage` page:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    expense: state.expenses.find(
      expense => expense.id === props.match.params.id // here, you will get error the params of undefined
    )
  };
};
```

You will get `params of undefined` error because you wrap the `withRouter` by using react-redux `connect`, in fact, you should wrap react-redux `connect` by a `withRouter`:

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(EditExpensePage));
```

After moving HOC wrapping the `match` key of props won't be undefined.

Comment: placing href was my stupidy. Since <Link/> was not working, I tried withRouter to move on. I implemented withRouter the way you did and  it is working. The thing is when I wrap my component with <Route/> those parameters already should be injected, right.

Comment: @Yilmaz, I'm a little confused, Is my answer right or not?

Comment: You are partially right. I ll give you upvote for that. But my main concern <Link/> is not working in ssr and i wanna know why

Comment: @Yilmaz, why you guess it does not work in SSR? what's your evidence? what you want from `<Link>` to do?

Comment: if I write the code without "withRouter" it is not working. there might be something with the <StaticRouter context={{}}/> context object. context object's job is to deal with the redirecting but I could not implement it in my app.

Comment: @Yilmaz, I read your whole project, in fact, you do not use `react-router` in a proper way, I never have seen this usage before, using `react-universal-component` and passing just a name is very weird. it is obvious you would have several issues. why you do not use the proper way of [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) and why you didn't see some [good implementation example](https://github.com/wellyshen/react-cool-starter). I seriously offer you to read [this route config](https://github.com/wellyshen/react-cool-starter/blob/master/src/routes.tsx)

Comment: I really appreciate your effort to help. I want to understand everything that I write so I can build my own boilerplate as I learn. It will take longer time but will make me a better developer.

Comment: You're my man dear @Yilmaz bro, your approach is awesome, I did it a few years ago and I get response. but I followed the docs and they made me more stronger. also I read good examples. I hope you will reach to your goal.